# change div to fixed when scrolled to

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, css-position, fixed

So I've seen a lot of answers to change a `div` from `position: absolute`; to `position: fixed`; when it hits a specific point like `300px` down the page; however, I want to know if instead of a specific point like `300px`, you can make it fixed once you hit that actual `div`? Since my page always launches at `100%` height/width and my nag is at the bottom, it will always be changing. Here's my code.

#### CSS:

```
nav {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:9999;
    margin:0;
    padding:25px 0;
}
```

---

#### JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
        var $cache = $('#nav'); 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $cache.css({'position': 'fixed'});
        }
        else {
            $cache.css({'position': 'absolute'});
        }
    }
        $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
        fixDiv();
});
```

---

I just want that `300` to be `#nav` so when it reaches it, it sticks.

Comment: Firstly, make your code in code block `ctrl+k`, Secondly i think you can use the following `$cache.css({'position': 'fixed !important'});`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `.offset()`.
So if `$('#nav').offset().top` equals to `$(window).scrollTop()`, your element should be at the top of the window.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vj5wm0uj/1/